# ASP.NET Core WebAPI XML Method argument deserialization

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to make a WebAPI controller on .NET Core 3.1 witch supports both JSON and XML as request/response content-type.

Controller works perfectly when it receive JSON with "application/json", but when it receive XML with "application/xml", method argument are created with default values, not values that was posted in request body.

Example project - https://github.com/rincew1nd/ASPNetCore_XMLMethods

Additional XML serializer in startup:

```
services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

Controller with method and test model:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost, Route("v1")]
        [Consumes("application/json", "application/xml")]
        [Produces("application/json", "application/xml")]
        public TestRequest Test([FromBody] TestRequest data)
        {
            return data;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class TestRequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Guid TestGuid { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string TestString { get; set; }
    }
```

P.S. Project contains Swagger for API testing purposes.

Comment: The sample Data for xml request need to be `TestGuid` instead of `testGuid` and `TestString` instead of `testString`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some more research i found that swagger generates wrong xml examples without even noticing custom naming of classes or properties.

I wrote custom schema for naming xml attributes as they are named by XML attributes.
Only problem i faced is that SchemaFilterContext doesn't provide description of properties of Enum type. So to name Enums i use custom attribute for swagger name and XMLElementAttribute on property with same names (yeah, it's junky but works).

```
public class XmlSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        //Try to find XmlRootAttribute on class
        var xmlroot = context.Type.GetAttributeValue((XmlRootAttribute xra) => xra);
        if (xmlroot != null)
        {
            schema.Xml = new OpenApiXml
            {
                Name = xmlroot.ElementName
            };
        }

        //Try to find XmlElementAttribute on property
        if (context.MemberInfo != null)
        {
            var xmlelement = context.MemberInfo.GetAttributeValue((XmlElementAttribute xea) => xea);
            if (xmlelement != null)
            {
                schema.Xml = new OpenApiXml
                {
                    Name = xmlelement.ElementName
                };
            }
        }

        //Try to find XmlEnumNameAttribute on enums
        if (context.Type.IsEnum)
        {
            var enumname = context.Type.GetAttributeValue((XmlEnumNameAttribute xea) => xea);
            if (enumname != null)
            {
                schema.Xml = new OpenApiXml
                {
                    Name = enumname.ElementName
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static class AttributeHelper
{
    public static TValue GetAttributeValue<TAttribute, TValue>(
        this Type type,
        Func<TAttribute, TValue> valueSelector)
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var att = type.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(TAttribute), true
        ).FirstOrDefault() as TAttribute;
        if (att != null)
        {
            return valueSelector(att);
        }
        return default(TValue);
    }
    public static TValue GetAttributeValue<TAttribute, TValue>(
        this MemberInfo mi,
        Func<TAttribute, TValue> valueSelector)
        where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        var att = mi.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(TAttribute), true
        ).FirstOrDefault() as TAttribute;
        if (att != null)
        {
            return valueSelector(att);
        }
        return default(TValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your xml post request body uses camel cases which results in the model binding as null.

Add `using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;` in `starup.cs` and try to configure like below code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Neocase <-> 1C Integration", Version = "v1" });
            c.SchemaFilter<XmlSchemaFilter>();
        });

    }
public class XmlSchemaFilter : Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (model.Properties == null) return;

            foreach (var entry in model.Properties)
            {
                var name = entry.Key;
                entry.Value.Xml = new OpenApiXml
                {
                    Name = name.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + name.Substring(1)
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about case sensitivity of xml and also didn't know where to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `FromBody` attribute for *application/xml*.

> When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header to select a formatter. In this example, the content type is "application/json" and the request body is a raw JSON string (not a JSON object).

[Using [FromBody]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody)

Comment: Thanks, but i am using content-type and accept headers in request when testing example project. And i want user to specify what is send in api.

Example post:
curl -X POST "http://localhost:60557/Test/v1" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><TestRequest>\t<TestGuid>3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6</TestGuid>\t<TestString>string</TestString></TestRequest>"